# Modifying a copied NSMutableDictionary also modifies the original

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an `NSMutableDictionary` called `source`, and then I create another this way:

```
NSMutableDictionary *new = [source copy];
```

But when I modify one of `new`'s values, the value of `source` is also modified. Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that iOS (and OSX) use shallow copies. That means the new collection has the same objects in it as the original. As the @danDedo said in his answer, your copy is non-mutable - that it, its a dictionary not a mutable dictionary (so you could not add or delete objects). But the objects are the same. So if these objects are themselves mutable, then changes in one place will affect all references (that is, all the objects in the copies).

The solution to this is to write your own "deep copy" (if you need it) - you can for sure find examples searching for "deep copy" here.

Answer (score 2):

You created a copy of the collection, but the collection holds pointers to objects.  So, the new copy also only holds pointers to objects (known as a shallow copy).

Print out both dictionaries and you can see that they both hold the same pointers.

Also, your "copy" is not a MutableArray...  you need to use mutableCopy for that.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the message copy to the receiver, shouldn't you be sending mutableCopy to create a mutable dictionary?  I am surprised that an exception wasn't thrown when you tried to mutate this object.

Comment: mutableCopy seems to be having the same effect

Comment: I deleted my last comment because it was wrong, but I misunderstood it too.  OP is not modifying the dictionary itself, but the contents of the pointers *inside* the dictionary (for example NSMutableString)